# List branches from one of the multiple remote repositories

Tags: git, github

I have two remote reposotories and I want to list out the branches from one of the remote repositories only.

git branch -r shows only the branches from the origin .

Answer (score 1):

Try `git remote show <name>` where `<name>` is the name of the remote you want to get details for. `git remote -v` will give you a list of available remotes.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -r` should give you the list of all remote branches (from both remotes), if you don't see branches from `origin2`, you probably haven't fetched changes from it :

```
git fetch origin2
```

---

To answer your "how to list branches from a specific remote ?" question :

- branches from `origin2` known to your local repo (update them by running `git fetch origin2`) :

  ```
  git branch -r --list "origin2/*"
  ```
- branches you can access on the remote server :

  ```
  git ls-remote origin2 "refs/heads/*"
  ```